# Avoiding orphan parts of a command

Tags: spacing, widows-orphans

I have a command that is used to print stuff with a certain structure:

```
\newcommand{\miracle}[2]{       
\textbf{#1}                 

#2

\bigskip
}
```

How can I ensure that the stuff printed by the two arguments (the bold and the nonbold text) do not get separated? 
Sometimes it happens that i get the bold line only at the end of a column, but i'd like to tell latex that the bold text must not be separated from the other.

Comment: You're telling TeX to do a paragraph break between `\textbf{#1}` and `#2`: a blank line counts as “end of paragraph”.

Comment: Do `\textbf{#1}\par\nobreak#2` instead of the blank line (which is an implicit `\par`).